# Is Venetian mirror possible in Autodesk Inventor?

Tags: design, mechanism, 3d-printing, 3d-model, visualization

I see there are things like glass and mirror in Autodesk Inventor Professional 2016 but is there a possibility to have Venetian mirror? So that from one side it would look like a mirror and from the other side it would look like a transparent glass?

Comment: Why do you want that? Those are cosmetic surface properties only.

Comment: Well, perhaps I demand too much... I would like to do animation of rotating object. That's too bad it may only look like a glass or mirror.

Comment: Can you make it mirrored for part of the animation while showing one side then stop, make it transparent, and record the second part (then stitch the two parts together)?

Comment: Yes, I can, but still that would be nice if Venetian mirror would exist in Inventor :)

Comment: It would be nice! But I think stitching two parts would be the quickest solution.

Comment: No problem, I will turn it from a comment to an official answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it in no way is related to robotics.

Comment: you can use materials that reflect like a mirror when rendering in Studio, not sure about the Venezian part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question about robotics.

Comment: How could question related to engineering design software not be connected with robotics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface properties like that are really only for cosmetic purposes so it is unlikely any CAD program has that option. However, you may be able to get the appropriate effect by assigning particular *faces* either glass or mirror texture.

Based on your added comments, I think the best option is simply to capture images or animation frames with whatever proper surface setting is needed for the required view angle. Then you can stitch the separate animation frames together to make it seem as though the component has the look you want.